# declaring in PHP application forms w/ radio buttons & check boxes to save

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm really confused about how to start on my PHP with radio buttons and check boxes.

How do I print out the option chosen by the user? 
Also, declaring lots of fields with similar name but with different answers.

It also needs to be connected to a mySQL database.

Comment: Please be more specific on what you want. Also, a quick Googleing should answer your question.

Comment: Well, there are sufficient number of articles available on the web on how to work with radio buttons and check boxes. Those could be a real good thing to get yourself started and comfortable with it

Answer (score 0):

checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="theoptions[]" value="1"> Option 1...
<input type="checkbox" name="theoptions[]" value="2"> Option 2...
<input type="checkbox" name="theoptions[]" value="3"> Option 3..
```

.

If user will submit checked 2 & 3 then $_REQUEST['theoptions'] will be array( 2, 3 )

To store in mysql you can create table for selected options for concrete user or implode() that array to store somethin like "2,3" or "2|3"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save an array in MYSQL I use serialize to save it in the mysql http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

and to get the array back then use http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

so it would look like something like

```
$options=$_GET['theoptions']; //never use $_REQUEST
serialize($options);
//save to mysql database
```

Comment: thanks but how do you declare them in PHP? (radio button, check boxes and select)

Comment: just do <?php echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"theoption1\" />"; ?>